# BroadcastReceiver onReceive() method is not called on device with code scanner

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am writing Android application for mobile device with scanner(Datalogic(JOYA TOUCH ANDROID) and I registered BroadcastReceiver in my application to listen device scanner result action. The problem is that, when I'm scanning some codes, my BroadcastReceiver method onReceive() is not calling.

```
    CustomReceiver receiver = new CustomReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("com.datalogic.decodewedge.decode_action");

    registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

And Broadcast Receiver code is simple, for test only.

```
public class CustomReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("CustomReceiver", "onReceiver");
}}
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="pl.hemilab.recievers.CustomReceiver" />
```

Here is device scanner settings. [Scanner settings picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2mGY.jpg)

This device allows to choose how to deliver action to another Android applications, via StartActivity, via StartService and Broadcast intent. 
Also tried to get scanner action via getting Activity intent, but also it's not working. 
Also tried to reset all scanner configurations and device configurations also. Didn't helped.
Why it's happening like that?

Comment: Did you try to enable the broadcast receiver from Manifest? It is like <receiver android:name="pl.hemilab.recievers.CustomReceiver" android:enabled="true" />

Comment: @AbduazizKayumov yes, still not working(

Comment: You should provide more code to give some reason about this problem. Where are you firing the receiver?

Comment: In the MainActivity onCreate() method. The thing is, I have another registered BroadcastReceiver's for another actions and they are working good.

Comment: In Manifest, try to declare the receiver like this: 
<receiver android:name="pl.hemilab.recievers.CustomReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.datalogic.decodewedge.decode_action" />
            </intent-filter>
</>

Comment: And I guess you don't have to register this broadcast receiver.
Just call: 
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("pl.hemilab.recievers.CustomReceiver");
intent.putExtra("data","Notice me senpai!");
sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: You may need to follow the official guidelines from
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.

Comment: Anyways, there should not be any problem if you follow the official guidelines. Otherwise, provide more code to get an answer. I don't think the above details are enough. Maybe, your scanner is not really working.